# Hollow Square Bracket Notation

Tags: functions, notation

This function appeared on my HW but I do not recognize the bracket symbols. I am thinking they might be an equivalent notation for absolute value, but I'm not sure and would appreciate any explanations!

[image]

Comment: I don't think that has a universally accepted meaning.  I've seen that used to describe the floor function, though these days it would be more common to write $\lfloor\,x\,\rfloor$.  Is there any context?  Are any properties of $f(x)$ mentioned or discussed?

Comment: It's not a standard notation. There should be some context, e.g. is the symbol defined in your course?

Comment: All math notation has meaning depending on context. The notation should be explained somewhere. The best thing would be to ask whoever wrote the homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you @lulu, I think it probably is the floor function.